# BigQuery get difference between event_timestamp from firebase analytics and current timestamp

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm using bigquery integrated with Firebase Analytics and I'm trying to query the difference between an event_timestamp and current timestamp in hours. I'm doung something like this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_DIFF(event_timestamp, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), HOUR)
FROM my-firebase-analytics-table
WHERE event_name = 'session_start'
```

With this query I'm getting an error in `TIMESTAMP_DIFF(event_timestamp, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), HOUR)`. The error is:

`No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP_DIFF for argument types: INT64, TIMESTAMP, DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signature: TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP, DATE_TIME_PART)`

For what I could get for the tests I made is that the event_timestamp field is not an TIMESTAMP field. Is their a way I can transform it into a TIMESTAMP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually if it is a INT64 - it is presented in milliseconds from epoch

To convert to timestamp - use [TIMESTAMP_MILLIS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_millis)(int64_expression)  as in below example

```
#standardSQL   
SELECT TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(event_timestamp), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), HOUR)
FROM `project.dataset.my-firebase-analytics-table`
WHERE event_name = 'session_start'
```

Obviously, it can be INT64 for seconds or microseconds - so you will use respective counterparts in this case - TIMESTAMP_MICROS or TIMESTAMP_SECONDS

Comment: Firebase Analytics -> BigQuery stores the event_timestamp as microseconds: "event_timestamp INTEGER The time (in microseconds, UTC) at which the event was logged on the client." The entire schema is documented here: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en